# Function returning multiple plots inside Rmarkdown plots printed side by side instead one above the other

Tags: r, function, plot, r-markdown

I created a function to generate multiple graphs, as a helper function. The problem is that when I knit the document those graphs stay side by side and I intended for them to be one above the other using a function.

Example:

````
---
title: "R Notebook"
output:
pdf_document: default
---

mult_plot <- function(x) {
    plot(x)
    barplot(x)
    hist(x)
}

x <- 1:10

mult_plot(x)
```
````

I would like to use a function because I have a lot of plots and a lot of variables to plot and I prefer not to copy and paste individual code for each one of them.
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To stack plots vertically, you can try adding `fig.align='center'` to your chunk options.

Comment: Thanks! Did not expect it was so simple!